# Image background keep overlapping the text?

Tags: image-processing, processing

I'm trying to have random text and backgrounds pop up when i click the mouse, however, when I click, the text is shown for less than half a second before a new background appears and hides the text

This is how my mouse pressed looks:

```
String mySentence = "Lose.txt";

String[] lose;

float mx = 20;

int posX = 0;
int posY = 0;

int butterflyX = 100;
int butterflyY = 100;

PImage v1;
PImage bf;
float xpos, ypos;

boolean playing = false;

//sentence
boolean showMySentence = false;
int mySentenceTimer = 0;

PImage [] backgrounds = new PImage[5];
int bg;
int currentBgNumber = 0;

void setup(){
  size(800,501);


  backgrounds = new PImage[5];
  backgrounds[0] = loadImage("field.jpg");
  backgrounds[1] = loadImage("galaxy.jpg");
  backgrounds[2] = loadImage("tokyo.jpg");
  backgrounds[3] = loadImage("water.jpg");
  backgrounds[4] = loadImage("paris.jpg");

 // mySentence = loadStrings(loseFile);

  PFont myFont;
  myFont = createFont("Futura", 30,true);
  textFont(myFont);
  fill(255);


}

void draw(){  

   image(backgrounds[currentBgNumber], 0, 0);



if (showMySentence) {
    fill(255);
    textSize(20);
    text(mySentence, width/2, height/2);
    showMySentence = millis() < mySentenceTimer; 

}

void mousePressed() {

   currentBgNumber++;
   if (currentBgNumber>4)
      currentBgNumber=0;


   if (random(1) < .5) {
    mySentence = "lose.txt" + "!";
    mySentenceTimer = millis() + 3000; 
    showMySentence = true;
            }

      }
```

From what I see, after the background runs, the text should run after, but I guess not. I would appreciate it if you could show me what needs to be fixed, thank you :)

Comment: That's because the `draw()` loop paints over it immediately. For your text to be drawn longer, it would have to be redrawn in the `draw()` loop too. I'll write you a code snippet to show a way you could fix this.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thank you, I'll try that out!

Answer (score 0):

As promised (you can copy and paste this snippet in a Processing IDE and it'll run. Then play around until you get the results that you want and adapt it into your own code):

```
// a couple variables I'll use to manage the text's appearance
String mySentence = "";
boolean showMySentence = false;
int mySentenceTimer = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  // background paints over everything ~60 times per second (or whatever fps you did set up)
  background(0);

  // this would go at the end of the draw() loop
  if (showMySentence) {
    fill(255);
    textSize(20);
    text(mySentence, width/2, height/2);
    showMySentence = millis() < mySentenceTimer; // flip the boolean after some time (2 seconds here)
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  // this would replace the part of the mouseClicked() method where you draw the sentence
  if (random(1) < .5) {
    mySentence = "your sentence here";
    mySentenceTimer = millis() + 2000; // show text but only for 2 seconds (I guessed that you might want that, but nevermind if that's not the case)
    showMySentence = true;
  }
}
```

I'll hang around in case you have further questions. Have fun!

Comment: Hi, thank you! I'm trying to string the text together now in the mousePressed loop but the list of text isn't showing and instead it just shows "lose.txt !" and I can't seem to add my randomLose file into the sentence statement.. Thank you again for the help :)  ```        
    mySentence = "lose.txt" + "!"; ```

Comment: @SamanthaSalanga Please update your post with the new informations and what you want out of it, it'll be easier for me to sort out.

Comment: I think I've almost got it! I had to just move and fix some of my side of the code. Thank you so much again! :)

Comment: Thanks again for the help!